# Privilege to be the "special function" and commands {\rm abc} and \text{abc}. (MathJax)

Tags: discussion, mathjax

In the point 11 of [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) there is written that for "special functions" (it shouldn't be understood as a mathematical function btw.) like sine we can simply use \sin  to get $\sin.$

Sometimes I wonder whether the thing that I am going to write is the "special function". So I just check for example $\Hom$ and get what you just see. I then use {\rm Hom} or \text{Hom} (or let it be ugly, i.e $Hom$). On the other hand things like $\projlim$ are settled.

I know that in preamble I can use \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}, but still I feel that a few more operators could be added to be the "special function".

So my question is the following. Are there any updates of "special functions" and if so is it possible that after the next one I will be able to use \Hom,\End and \Lin without hesitation?

Be understanding couse I have no clue how the MathJax is governed so my question may be silly.

Comment: By the way: you should use `\operatorname{Hom}` (if you don't `\DeclareMathOperator`). That gives correct spacing.

Comment: There were some discussions about possibility for each user to add their own set of macros. But this is probably not going to be implemented. See, for example: [Personal MathJax Macros/Shortcuts?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12155/personal-mathjax-macros-shortcuts) or [Specific Latex commands for user's account](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11870/specific-latex-commands-for-users-account) (And other posts linked there.)

Comment: Note that a half solution was given here: [Personalised LATEX commands for users](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/personalised-latex-commands-for-users)

Comment: @MartinSleziak do you have a way to make the title of cited questions appear instead of the link or you copy the title and transform it as a hyperlink?

Comment: @Surb The manual way: `[Question title](http://wherever/it/goes.to)`.

Comment: @Surb I just copy the title and use `[title](url)` syntax. But - as expected - some users have [bookmarklet for that](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19522/markdown-for-obtaining-the-question-title-from-url/19526#19526).

Comment: @Daniel and Martin: ok thank you, I thought so, but I hoped for a magical trick :). BTW: this could be an interesting feature (that is just for SE links).

Comment: @Surb In question and answer bodies, if you have a naked link to a question (on the same SE site, or on the associated main/meta; unfortunately it doesn't seem to work cross-site), that gets resolved to the question title. But comments are second-class citizens.

Comment: @Surb It reffers to [this objects](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#opname). But if I understood it correctly it makes some modification on your web browser and it substitudes \Hom% by \operatorname{Hom}. It just work browserwise, not globally (or even SE userwise).

Comment: @DanielFischer This is somehow sad, even more on meta where a high percentage of participation is through comments (at least this is what I observed until now).

Comment: @FallenApart Yes, this is why I called it a "half-solution".

Comment: MathJaX tries to emulates LaTeX math markup. So the question is whether LaTeX will include new macros for Hom, End, Lin... The answer is "it's extremely unlikely". A lot of legacy LaTeX code defines personalized macros for these, and an update would break the code. Note that sometimes people want $\mathrm{Hom}$, sometimes they want $\mathtt{Hom}$, sometimes $\mathsf{Hom}$... so it's far from being a simple matter. Letting everyone define what they want is (IMO) simpler.

Comment: By the way, note that spacing will be terrible if you simply use `\mathrm`. You should use something like `\operatorname`. Compare $\mathrm{End} X$ and $\operatorname{End} X$. You can also do combinations, eg. `\mathop{\mathtt{End}} X` will yield $\mathop{\mathtt{End}} X$ (as opposed to $\mathtt{End}X$).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I see, but sadly I stay with an ugly $End(X).$

Comment: @DanielFischer: using `\operatorname*{Res}` puts the subscripts and superscripts directly below and above the name: $\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=0}f(z)$. This can be quite useful and is another reason to use `\operatorname`

Comment: @robjohn It looks really neat. Good to know.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with the spirit of this question.  It drives me crazy that I have to type in \mathbb{R} for the reals.  When writing a LaTeX doc, I'm sure that every user here puts a command in the preamble to make $\R$ or $\RR$ give the desired output.  Why can't we do that here for standard things like $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$, etc.?

Comment: @SpamIAm  With my Chrome extension, I type `\Re%` and get `\operatorname{Re}` , or type `\R ` and get `\mathbb{R}`. I should probably publish this as a separate extension... are there other commands you'd like to see shortened?

Comment: Very similar questions were posted [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6443/newcommand-ord-operatornameord) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12709/way-to-make-spec-a-command). (I'd say almost a duplicate.)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that no one mentioned `\hom` which produces $\hom$.

Comment: I will add that a new answer mentioning a Chrome extension, which can help with custom commands, was added [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12709/way-to-make-spec-a-command/20818#20818).